# SqlAlchemy: insert statement, actual SQL and skipping fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SqlAlchemy model:

```
class SchemaVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schema_version'

    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, primary_key=True)
    version   = Column(String)
    notes     = Column(String)
```

The closest I could come is:

```
statement = insert(SchemaVersion).values(version='v1.0.0',
                                         notes='Initial schema')

print(statement.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
```

`engine` is the engine I'm using (Postgres)

The resulting printed SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO schema_version (timestamp, version, notes) VALUES (%(timestamp)s, 'v1.0.0', 'Initial schema')
```

The problem is of course `%(timestamp)s`

How can I pass `now()` as value or let SqlAlchemy to use the default for me? If I try:

```
statement = insert(SchemaVersion).values(timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                                         version='v1.0.0',
                                         notes='Initial schema')
```

I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Don't know how to literal-quote value datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 21, 9, 50, 11, 732957)
```

Comment: You could pass `timestamp=func.current_timestamp()` and let the DB handle it, but why are interested in producing an SQL string with compiled literals in the first place?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, It worked. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's a bit unclear why you're interested in producing an SQL string with bound literals, you could avoid the fact that [only simple types such as `int` and `str` are supported](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) in this case by producing the timestamp in the database using for example `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
statement = insert(SchemaVersion).values(timestamp=func.current_timestamp(),
                                         version='v1.0.0',
                                         notes='Initial schema')
```

This would compile to something along the lines of

```sql
INSERT INTO schema_version (timestamp, version, notes)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'v1.0.0', 'Initial schema')
```